# Attached files not appearing for anonymous users in Drupal 7 View page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a page that's based on a View that lists a certain content type as a table. In this case 'Publications'. For some reason the field showing attached files does not show up on the list page generated by the Publications View, unless you're an authenticated user.

http://www.cca-roma.org/en/publications

However, on each individual page the attachment shows up fine:

http://www.cca-roma.org/en/site-conservation-during-rescue-excavations

The list page displays the attachments field fine if I'm logged in, otherwise it's hidden.

I've checked permissions, but I don't think that's the problem since the file does show up for anonymous users on the individual page, as in the above example. It seems to be an issue with the View. In the Advanced View settings, I have 'Hide Attachments in Summary' set to No.

Might I need to adjust the view template to enable the display of attached files to anonymous users? Or make a template for the specific attachment field?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered similar problem and found that it was related to the File Entity module. I needed to grant the permission "Document: Download any files" for the anonymous user.

After that the fields content is shown in view for anonymous user.

The problem was with the "Download link" formatter in Views.

Comment: Whilst file nodes *were* visible - e.g. /file/slug-based-on-filename, until this setting was turned on, the file field was not being displayed within the node it was attached to (i.e. as if the field had been moved into the 'Hidden' section in 'Manage display').  D7.